# F#: Disposing of resources that are inside a closure?

Tags: f#, closures, dispose

Suppose I create a closure over a resource such as a StreamWriter:

```
let currentdir = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()
let testfile = sprintf "%s\\%s" currentdir "closuretest.txt"

let getwriter() =
    let writer = new StreamWriter(testfile, false)
    (fun() -> writer.Write "test")
```

Is there a way to close the StreamWriter when I'm done with the closure? Or do I need to replace the closure with a wrapper object that has a Write() method and a Dispose() method? (This is of course a trivialized example.) Thanks all.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, you should to replace the closure with an `IDisposable` object with a method and a `Dispose()`.  (Alternatively, return a tuple of closures, the second of which calls `Close()` or whatnot, and leave it to the caller like that.)

(While you're at it, `System.IO.Path.Combine()` should be used, rather than glueing together filenames with string formatting.)

Comment: Thank you very much Brian for the quick reply. The available F# material seems to talk about closures, and resource management, but not the two together.

Answer (score 3):

I sometimes do:

```
let getwriter() =
  let writer = new StreamWriter(testfile, false)
  (fun() ->
    use writer = writer
    writer.Write "test")
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply Dr. Harrop. That looks like it keeps the work of opening the file out of the closure, yet still closes the file as the closure exits. I'll be using that in the future.

Answer (score 1):

`IDisposable` is about *deterministically*, i.e. explicitly releasing resources. Thus if the closure doesn't somehow provide a disposing functionality by itself, the resource cannot be release deterministically any more.

As Brian pointed out, this can be more or less explicit, though implementing `IDisposable` is preferrable as `use` + IDisposable automatically takes care of releasing resources in case of exceptions.

However, sometimes it's sufficient to completely hide the disposable resource and get a closure of what's to be done instead.

```
let getWriter body = 
    use writer = new StreamWriter(testfile, false)
    body(writer)

// ...

getWriter (fun writer -> writer.Write "test")
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply Dario. From what I've heard, a closure is represented as just another .NET object. I wonder if at some point we'll get a way to add finalize/dispose code to it.